# How do I prevent cloth from exploding and growing continuously? (Blender 2.91)

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am having a hard time attaching a cape to my character. For some reason, when I press play, it continuously expands the mesh. I messed with the collision settings and tried applying all transforms to the mesh. What I am doing wrong?

Here are reference pictures:

[image: Cloth begins to expand]

[image: Cloth continuous to expand]

[image: Cloth Settings 1]

[image: Cloth Settings 2]

[image: Cloth Settings 3]

[image: Modifiers]

Comment: Is scale applied?  Do you have any other modifiers on the cloth object?

Comment: Usually helps start from scratch or with simple primitives to achieve basics. I would say it is collision issue that would be hard to discover without your simplified blend. Try apply scale.

Comment: @Nathan yes, scale is applied and there is cloth followed by a hook empty modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work I switched the order of the modifiers in the modifiers tab, and put the empty modifier, which I used to attack the mesh to my object, on top and the cloth modifier on the bottom. I also used subdivisions rather than using loop cuts on my mesh.